# NonLinearModelFitting constant offset problem

Tags: fitting

I have written the following code:

```
fit6peakslorentz[data_, minpos_] := Module[
{pltdta, fit, fitfu, pltfit, fit1, mini, maxi, amp0, begin, end},
pltdta = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All];
(* start vals *)
mini = Min[Transpose[data][[2]]];
maxi = Max[Transpose[data][[2]]];
(* x00 = Select[data, #[[2]] \[Equal] mini &][[1]][[1]];*)
amp0 = mini - maxi;
begin = Last[Transpose[data][[1]]];
end = First[Transpose[data][[1]]];
(* now fit *)
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
  data,
  c + q1 (y1^2/((x - x01)^2 + y1^2))
   + q2 (y2^2/((x - x02)^2 + y2^2))
   + q3 (y3^2/((x - x03)^2 + y3^2))
   + q4 (y4^2/((x - x04)^2 + y4^2))
   + q5 (y5^2/((x - x05)^2 + y5^2))
   + q6 (y6^2/((x - x06)^2 + y6^2)),
  {
   {c, maxi},
   {q1, amp0}, {x01, minpos[[1]]}, {y1, 1},
   {q2, amp0}, {x02, minpos[[2]]}, {y2, 1},
   {q3, amp0}, {x03, minpos[[3]]}, {y3, 1},
   {q4, amp0}, {x04, minpos[[4]]}, {y4, 1},
   {q5, amp0}, {x05, minpos[[5]]}, {y5, 1},
   {q6, amp0}, {x06, minpos[[6]]}, {y6, 1}
   },
  x
  ];
fitfu[x_] = c + q1 (y1^2/((x - x01)^2 + y1^2))
 + q2 (y2^2/((x - x02)^2 + y2^2))
 + q3 (y3^2/((x - x03)^2 + y3^2))
 + q4 (y4^2/((x - x04)^2 + y4^2))
 + q5 (y5^2/((x - x05)^2 + y5^2))
 + q6 (y6^2/((x - x06)^2 + y6^2)) /. fit["BestFitParameters"];
pltfit = 
 Plot[fitfu[x], {x, begin, end}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red];
 Print[Show[pltdta, pltfit, PlotRange -> {{begin, end}, All}]];
 fit["ParameterTable"]
 ]
```

but it fails to fit the way I want it to.  Entering the peaks manually the code finds them fine but the offset is all wrong:
[image]

Comment: Can you give us access to your data? Pastebin perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

This is an extended comment rather than an answer.  I (crudely) digitized the data from about $x=600$ to $x=1000$ and gave initial estimates for what I would call the 6 troughs (rather than peaks) and your code seemed to work fine:

```
fit6peakslorentz[data, {691, 728, 765, 791, 827, 864}]
```

[image: curve fit]

As @MarcoB suggested, making available the subset of the data you used along with the initial values used would go a along way to determine the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the program was taking the six peaks on the right side of my graph and averaging them to find the constant I had asked it to look for.  I solved this by removing the second half of my data, but I believe it could also be solved by adding more troughs in the equation to account for them.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good.  You might consider marking your answer as the accepted answer to bring formal closure to the question.